# Move from Xamarin to native(Swift/Kotlin)?

Tags: xamarin, native

We currently have an app in Xamarin, which is Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS with a shared PCL (no Xamarin.Forms). It currently is a very complicated app and we would like to remake screen by screen the app, and move away from Xamarin to a Swift and a Kotlin app in the meantime.

Is this possible? We don't have the time nor money to remake the app completely at once.

I have looked into making new screens as external libraries, and then bind that library, but I think that's making it a bit too complicated.

Comment: What do you mean by native? Xamarin is used to make native app only. Did you used Xamarin Forms?

Comment: @GauravKP Sorry if I was unclear, I want to migrate to Swift & Kotlin.

Comment: You can only use a part of your design file for Android. If you had used Xamarin Form then you can&#39;t reuse design.

Comment: As stated in the question, we use Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS, so no Xamarin.Forms, I will edit the question to clarify this

Comment: @vrwim https://github.com/mono/embeddinator-4000

Comment: In that case you can reuse designer files and resources

Comment: @SushiHangover that looks like what I want; thanks for the link

Answer (score 0):

you can reuse the assets and resources only but not the code because you are using Xamarin.Forms not Xamarin.Android + Xamarin.iOS.

in your project you don't have any android XML design files and no iOS storyboard even the logic is different with the .cs files because you are not using the Android Java SDK or iOS SDK directly.
If you were use mono and mono touch directly without using the PCL (Xamarin.Forms) project then you can rewrite the code with minor changes with names of method, properties... etc.